# LocBaml include previous translations

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to combine a previous translation when extracting the csv file from an application? 
Or any other tool that could do this job for me?

I can’t really see how could i use locbaml if i had to translate everything from scratch every time i add a new control in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using something like [WinMerge](http://www.winmerge.org/) to merge the existing file with the old one.

Comment: i was hoping for something more automated than just a generic tool, more like a better version of locbaml (since its allready open source).

Anywyay, i am going to evaluate the WinMerge application and come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my open source addin http://easybaml.codeplex.com, which combines previous translations automatically. Right now it uses .resx instead of .csv, which can be changed if needed.